# Confirming a Transaction using Venmo API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, venmo

So I'm new to Ruby on Rails and am making a web app that uses venmos API. I currently have a link set up that sends the user to a payment page on venmo with a price based on other information. I'm wondering if there is a way to confirm the amount paid. From the information in the link below it sounds like I have to use braintree. Thanks in advance!

https://developer.venmo.com/docs/widgets/venmo-button

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct - if you are looking to facilitate payments between people and merchants, the best way to do this is to use Braintree's [v.zero SDK](https://www.braintreepayments.com/v.zero).